# How to check if an array contains all elements from one of another arrays

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following input arrays:

```
permissions = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,19];
allowedPermissions1 = [1,2];
allowedPermissions2 = [3,4,5,6];
```

What I'm trying to do is to create a helper function to determine if the parent array (in this case `permissions`) contains every element from at least one of the other arrays (`allowedPermissions1` or `allowedPermissions2` - can be more than 2).

My current implementation is the following one:

```
allowedPermissions1.every(x => permissions.includes(x)) || allowedPermissions2.every(x => permissions.includes(x));
```

I was thinking to have an array of arrays as param for helper and to apply the above logic for every sub-arrays (with `OR` between results).

In fact, to apply the `every` function on every sub-array and then `some` for results.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: `[allowedPermissions1,allowedPermissions2].some(p=>p.every(x=>permissions.includes(x))` should indeed work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Array.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to test each permission array to see if all its elements are present in the permissions array.

So, if *any* of the allowedPermissions arrays has *all* of its values present in the permissions set, we return true

I've updated to make permissions a Set, since this should be more efficient.

```js
permissions = new Set([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,19]);
allowedPermissions =[ [1,2], [3,4,5,6]];

let result = allowedPermissions.some(allowed => { 
    return allowed.every(el => permissions.has(el));
});

console.log("Result: ", result);
```

Another example (permissions does not include all required values):

```js
permissions = new Set([1,4,5,6,7,8,9,19]);
allowedPermissions =[ [1,2], [3,4,5,6]];

let result = allowedPermissions.some(allowed => { 
    return allowed.every(el => permissions.has(el));
});

console.log("Result: ", result);
```